# Date fields not getting loaded from source/expression to target while using odbc connection

Tags: amazon-redshift, informatica

I have columns like a int, b varchar,c timestamp in my table x (redshift) and am trying to load those three columns into another  table b(redshift) by using a mapping m1, in that am using odbc connection's.
Issue is am able to load the data for all the columns except date fields (c **timestamp**) whether those are from src or expression.
In place of date null values are storing.
`Mapping ran successful without any issue/warning`.

> Note: am using odbc connection's because I need to call stored procedure in Post sql.

Comment: Is timestamp the source or target datatype? What is the datatype in the mapping?

Comment: @Maciejg, in target the datatype is timestamp and am taking date from expression transformation which is date/time which is equal to timestamp as per iics.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response.
As I modified the lookup transformation then I resolved the issue.
In lookup mapping I just modified the multiple matches  to return all rows then the date fields are getting loaded from source/expression transformation to target.